# Julia accessing specific Matrix elements using vectors as indexes

Tags: arrays, matrix, julia

Suppose I have a 4*2 matrix as follows:

```
a = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6; 7 8]
4×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2
 3  4
 5  6
 7  8
```

I want to access the matrix using a vector specifying which element I want to access in each column. In NumPy from python, I would do the following command:

```
a[[1,3], [1,2]]

# expected output:
1×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 1(as a[1,1])  6(as a[3,2])
```

but in Julia, I got the following matrix:

```
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2
 5  6
```

How can I do it in an julia way?

Comment: I think it's not the best way to learn a programming language to say, "I expect to do ... in julia, in the same way, I did it in Python". Julia is Julia and Python is Python. Using them as they are and in their specific way would be best instead of trying to imitate the behaviors. Otherwise, what would be the difference between these?

Comment: @Shayan Sorry for my wording, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: Inspired by DNF answer:

```
julia> a[CartesianIndex.([1 3], [1 2])]
1×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  6
```

seems to me the right balance of clarity and similarity to OP.

ORIGINAL answer:

Maybe not the optimal way, but:

```
[a[x...] for x in [[[1,1]] [[3,2]]]]
```

works.

Note that this returns a row vector, like in the OP. In Julia there is a difference between a vector and a matrix. A matrix with one row or one column is not the same as a vector.

The `[[]]` notation is to let `hcat` handle vector elements correctly. If a vector output is good enough, then: `[[1,1],[3,2]]` is enough.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am a little confused about the broadcast behavior of Julia and when to use it (it seems to be used more frequently than that of Numpy in Python). Do have any suggested readings on that?

Comment: Yes, broadcasting is very important in Julia, and it works extremely well. Here's the most well-known blog post on the subject, written by one of the main designers. A few years old, but excellent: https://julialang.org/blog/2017/01/moredots/

Answer (score 2):

The syntax `a[i, j]` is syntax sugar for `getindex(a, i, j)`. You can broadcast `getindex` to get the desired behavior (unfortunately, you cannot broadcast the `[]` syntax itself):

```
getindex.(Ref(a), [1,3], [1,2])
```

You must protect `a` itself against being broadcasted, by wrapping it in a `Ref`.

Comment: Change `[1,3]` to `[1 3]` (etc.) to get the output shape in OP.

Comment: Yeah, but I suspect that output shape is inspired by numpy's row-major layout. Vector output seems more idiomatic for Julia.